# Integrated Graphics Requirments for Newer Laptops?

Tags: performance, windows, installation, opengl, hardware

I'm buying a 10th Gen Intel Core, HP laptop. The specs say it only has an Intel Graphics Coprocessor.

Will it run blender 2.8?

[https://www.amazon.com/2020-HP-Touchscreen-Premium-Laptop/dp/B081SM57RY/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081SM57RY)

Thanks.

Comment: This is not the site to ask for hardware recommendations, they are considered [off topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6). Please take the [tour] to understand how this site works. For broad questions or opinions a forum format  like [blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/forum/s) might be more appropriate.

Comment: read: [Hardware Requirements (Blender 2.8x)](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) and [supported hardware](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware)

Comment: "*Will it run blender 2.8?*" Yes. "*Will it run Blender with good performance?*" No, probably enough for casual hobby, bot not for complex or heavy professional work

Comment: Thanks @Duarte Farrajota Ramos I posted my question on https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/epv9qt/will_new_laptop_with_integrated_graphics_run/

Answer (score 0):

It will run Blender on the integrated graphics, but it will not be smooth for more complex scenes in Eevee, you need dedicated GPU to feel the full benefit of the the new render engine, like GTX 1650 4gb at least, the more VRAM memory it has... the better, some scenes or models need large amount of video memory to render out.